# Does small chip on a tire merit tire replacement

Tags: tires, wheels, damage

while cleaning the car I’ve noticed a small chip on a front tire. It looks like it was created after close encounter with a pavement curb. The tires are new and done maybe 300 miles. The chip is of maybe 1.5mm depth at the deepest point and of size 1 x 1.5cm, roughly. I would like to know if it creates any risk or if this tire is likely to break due to that?
[image: with dimensions]
[image: no dimensions]

Answer (score 1):

Unless it's really deep ie 1 cm plus not immediate but would recommend sort out soon as it's on side wall higher risk of blow out if driven and Left